# Best practice for mixing release / debug code in web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, webstorm

I'm developing a simple browser-based two player game. My current focus is on the backend so I want to see both player's states, but I don't want to work with two separate browsers, so I added HTML and Javascript for an extra player on the same page:

```
...
<button id="doTheThingButton">DO IT</button>
<span id="score">10</span>
<!-- <DEBUG AREA> -->
<button id="doTheThingButton2">DO IT2</button>
<span id="score2">10</span>
<!-- </DEBUG AREA> -->
<script>
    ...
    function fetchCurrentScore() { ... }
    function doTheThing() { ... }
    // <DEBUG AREA>
    function fetchCurrentScore2() { ... }
    function doTheThing2() { ... }
    // </DEBUG AREA>
</script>
```

These elements will also be useful in the future of the app, so I'd like to keep them around; but I want to be able to easily test both versions.

What frameworks exist to allow me to do so (if any)? Are there standalone frameworks that can be comfortably used with WebStorm?

Comment: What language do you code the backend in?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Use GIT or other CVS and have two different branches.

One is production code that you distribute to client

Second one has this additional code. After changing production branch, rebase dev from production:

```
git checkout production
git add .
git commit -m "Supper feature"
git checkout dev
git rebase dev
```

This also can be achieved with `git stash` command that does not requires additional branch